# Running a streaming operation ONLY on the node which contains the relevant KEY

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

Let's say I have a large IStreamMap on a large cluster and I *only* want to do an operation on a few keys. I could just right a filter expression as shown below, but my understanding is that this will run on all nodes. And 99% of the nodes will be forced to stream the map even though ultimately nothing comes out of it. Is there a way to get the Hazelcast jet cluster to ONLY run the operation on the nodes that correspond to those keys? The code that ought to work is below, but I don't think it's efficient. (In my case, I might be running this operation many times on large distributed maps, so I would not want each node to try to execute this operation if I can tell ahead of time that 99% of the nodes are not relevant to the selected keys.)

```
final IStreamMap<String, Integer> streamMap = instance1.getMap("source");
    // stream of entries, you can grab keys from it
             streamMap.stream()
                    .filter(key -> key == 1 || key = 9999999)
                    .forEach(key -> <do something interesting>));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IStreamMap` was removed from Hazelcast Jet three years ago, I think. You should use Jet through its [Pipeline API](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/pipeline).

You can try using a `map` source with a predicate:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
BatchStage<Entry<K, V>> stage = p.readFrom(Sources.map("name", 
        (Map.Entry<K, V> mapEntry) -> myCondition(mapEntry), 
        e -> e));
```

This will still scan the entire map, though. If you simply have a set of keys you're interested in, then perhaps a better match for your use case is [`IMap.executeOnKeys()`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html#executeOnKeys-java.util.Set-com.hazelcast.map.EntryProcessor-).